# Is it possible to send a list of objects or strings as a parameter to a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Her is my code

```
foreach (var comboBox in this.m_storage.ColumnComboList)
{
    comboBox.OnClientSelectedIndexChanged = string.Format(
       "function(sender, args){{ComboColList(sender, args, '{0}', '{1}', '{2}');}}",
       comboBox.ID,
       comboBox.ClientID,
       list???);
}
```

The list??? is the third parameter and is a list of strings. When I check the parameter in debug mode I can only see string methods. There must be a way for where I can send a list of strings to the client side and access the values.

Comment: [JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/a/259557/55209) is what you need to pass complex objects between client ans server.

Comment: See the html code that results and how the parameter are converted into html attributes.

Comment: @RASG yes that would do just fine.