# Cross-language configuration for Java or .NET

Tags: java, .net, language-agnostic, configuration

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239832/how-do-you-share-configuration-information-or-business-rules-between-languages) but didn't see a good answer.
I'm interested specifically in configuration files, say in XML. Are there cross-language standard/tools for reading config files? XML itself is just a medium, but I want tools and libraries and standards, like those existing in .NET's [ConfigurationSection class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsection.aspx).

My main targets are Java and .NET.

Answer (score 0):

I came across that question. I know that question is more than a decade old, but today YAML can be an answer to the question. YAML community also maintains a list of libraries and tools for a wide range of programming languages.

For details, check the YAML home page: https://yaml.org/